# phpmyadmin forbidden in Nginx although permited

Tags: nginx, php, permissions, configuration, phpmyadmin

I fail to understand why entrance to PHPmyadmin is forbidden (`http://my_ip/phpmyadmin`). Here's what I did to install it:

On a pure Ubuntu 16.04 machine (server, xenial) I've installed LEMP with php-fpm 7.0. Nginx conf is default:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade nginx mysql-server php-fpm php-mysql -y
```

I then installed PMA and **permitted** it:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-mcrypt -y
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html/
chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html
chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html
```

I really fail to understand what's wrong from the error log:

> directory index of "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/" is forbidden

What might cause PMA to be forbidden?

### Update - general:

- My [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b0a67c4ee7a7786801d956f727264a22).
- My [fastcgi.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ec2ca4bf28fbfe1ac0a63082f7fc69b).

### Update for Jenny:

I removed the symlink and added this conf inside the `http` block in `nginx.conf` and restarted the server, but no change is seen:

```
server {    
    location /phpmyadmin {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        root /usr/share;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see the permissions of every directories in that path ? Have you see [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687774/ubuntu-14-nginx-php5-fpm-installed-phpmyadmin-but-403-forbidden-access) Can you show your nginx config file ?

Comment: I've added my Nginx conf and my fastcgi conf.

Comment: This answer is so helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370993/1770571
It works for me!

Answer (score 8):

When you symlink a directory, you are telling nginx that "when you need to use `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin`, you should instead look at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`. And that directory is not under your webroot directory, so nginx won't be using it.

Instead of using a symlink, tell nginx to start using that directory directly. Example:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
     index index.php index.html index.htm;
     root /usr/share;
}
```

That will tell nginx that the location `/phpmyadmin` lives under `/usr/share` instead of under `/var/www/html/`.

Or, if the `/usr/` and the `/var/` file systems are on the same partition, you could do a hard link instead of a symlink. But that's likely to cause problems for you if you ever change the partition layout.

Comment: Jenny I've edited the question and added an update for you.

Comment: @ALTegani If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//serverfault.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: when I remove the symbolic link I have a 404

Answer (score 2):

The message

> directory index of "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/" is forbidden

indicates that nginx can't find the configured index document, so it tries to list the files (which is forbidden).

Check your `index` directive in your nginx configuration. It should contain `index.php` for phpMyAdmin.

Example:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

Comment: Please edit your complete server block into your configuration, including your php fastcgi configuration.

Comment: Your nginx.conf is missing the complete configuration for running php scripts.

Comment: In great plea, please edit to add an example (should this come in `nginx.conf` or in a dedicated conf file?).

Comment: Using PHP scripts with nginx is very well documented. You can find the configuration easily with the search engine of your choice, and even on this site.

Comment: That's true, but for `phpmyadmin`, do you suggest me to use some global conf or particular conf (per script)?

Comment: Also, to complete the answer, this is need here, because this will be the first QA session that explains the "forbidden" problem, for PMA. I found no other session to explain that.